# Writing Minecraft panel in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, minecraft

I'm planning on writing a control panel for Minecraft in Rails but I don't have much experience with Java at all, Minecraft seems to have some standard remote connection and query tools, but most conventional panels don't seem to use them. For example with McMyAdmin, I have disabled remote connectiona and the query, but it still seems to be able to communicate with the server after restarting it after I've edited the server configs to disable the settings.

What I'm asking is if anyone knows how McMyAdmin communicates with the Minecraft server, it comes with a plugin, but I've deleted that as well and it still seems to be able to communicate with the server, I know McMyAdmin is written in .NET and I believe it uses Mono as it's server, as it's cross platform.

If anybody could shed some light on this I'd be ever so greatful, just trying to get my head around the communication.

Answer (score 0):

McMyAdmin uses the plugin to open a socket that it can interact with(Not sure which features are provided using this plugin). The rest of the features are just from the Process instance that it creates. It also just edits the config files for a few things as well or runs commands using the input stream of the process.